# Installation ERROR(14.04): serious errors were found while checking the disk for /

Tags: system-installation

Everytime when I try to install Ubuntu 14.04 there is a message saying there are `serious errors while checking for drive /`. It also says `some files are not ready yet or no present`.

I have tried Ubuntu 13 and that doesn't work too but Ubuntu 12 works. What can I do?

Comment: Are you trying to upgrade or install, and when does the error occur (after or during install, etc)? [More information would be useful](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/9096/questions-with-too-little-information?cb=1)

Comment: I'm trying to install and this happens during installation

Comment: Is anything installed on the hard drive already?

Comment: the original OS is windows xp and this problem showed up from the first time so idk. And I already tried that on the duplicate but id doesn't seem to work

Comment: I now installed ubuntu 12.04 (someone recommended me this version in case i wasn't able to install the newest version). The newest version still doesn't work on my pc and I wonder why. And will this version (12.04) be supported for a while?